# Getting value from Hashmap with get or contains with apply method

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Which one is better way to get values from a hashmap?

First Option:

```
val hm = HashMap(...)
if(hm.contains(keyWhichIsDefinitelyInTheKeys)){
  hm(keyWhichIsDefinitelyInTheKeys)  ... //do stuff
} else {
 ... //do stuff
}
```

Second Option:

```
hm.get(keyWhichIsDefinitelyInTheKeys) match {
    case Some => ...
    case None => ...
} // do stuff
```

Comment: maybe you should rename `keyWhichIsDefinitelyInTheKeys` as it makes people think that `hm.get(keyWhichIsDefinitelyInTheKeys)` will always return non empty value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As dk14 said, if you are not sure that the Map contains the key, you 'd better use `get` which return an `Option`.

You can use `getOrElse` to set a default value if the key is not present in the `Map`.

If you don't have a default value to set, you can use `for` comprehension if `Option` contains `Some` and not a `None`

```
scala> val hm = Map( 1 -> "Hello")
hm: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> Hello)

scala> for (i <- hm.get(2) ) { println(i) }

scala> for (i <- hm.get(1) ) { println(i) }
Hello
```

Answer (score 1):

This is better for some key:

```
 hm.getOrElse(key, defaultValue)

 //or

 hm.getOrElse(key, sys.error(s"unexpected key: $key"))

 //or more generally

 hm.get(key).map(v => doStuff(v)).getOrElse(doOtherStuff)
```

You can't be 100% sure that `Map` contains key, except some type-level protection (compile-time check); however, if you do then `if` won't help you eitherway, so just:

```
 hm(keyWhichIsDefinitelyInTheKeys)
```

Comment: The question is about which one is more advised: checking if the hashmap contains a key or using the get ?

Comment: @stsatlantis `map` + `getOrElse` gives you a handy way to process options (including result from Map). But your question is self-contradictory as your variable name is `keyWhichIsDefinitelyInTheKeys` which means that you don't need to check if value is in the Map at all

Comment: @stsatlantis I mean, you're practically asking about - `if(contains(keyWhichIsAlwaysContained))`, which is same as `if(true)`

Answer (score 1):

In performance:

There is a test code: http://pastebin.com/TbM82S7H

That is its output: http://pastebin.com/7An1DZw5

(cpu: i5 4590K)

None of the two call is better in performance...